# Does VS code use different threads for different python terminal windows?

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio-code, terminal

Using `Python:Create terminal` in VScode View:Command palett and running in it `"python example_script.py"`. And it is possible to open multiple python programs and run them simultaneously.

Does anybody know if VScode natively supports threading for these terminals? I.e do they use different CPU threads or is there a way to make them behave this way?

Answer (score 0):

1. For multiple threads and do not require synchronous operation, you can try to change the way the debug output:
   (Please set `"console": "externalTerminal",` in the "`launch.json`" file in the "`.vscode`" folder.)

   [image]
2. For multi-threaded synchronous operation, except for the manual input of execution commands in two or more newly created terminals to make the code run synchronously, VSCode currently does not have other local support that supports this function.

   I have submitted an application for this feature in Github and we are looking forward to the realization of this feature:

   Github link: [Can VSCode automatically run python scripts in two or more terminals at the same time?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094)